# React Navigation - Reset Stack Router to initial route without knowing which route that is

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation with a Tab Router that has multiple Stack Routers nested inside.

In one screen that can be accessed in any of the stack routers, I want to have an action that resets the stack router (in which the screen is) to the initial route of that stack router.

For example: If I'm on the Home stack router I want it to reset to the Home screen, if I'm on the Profile stack router I want it to reset to the Profile screen.

Is there any way to do this?

Note: I'm not integrating with redux, would redux integration make this easier?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way could be without redux passing the redirected screen - the initial screen of that stack- as a parameter in every navigate.

For example,

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('CommonScreen1', { initial: 'Home'});
this.props.navigation.navigate('CommonScreen2', { initial: 'Home'});

// in CommonScreen2 do the reset to the this.props.navigation.state.params.initial

this.props.navigation.navigate('CommonScreen1', { initial: 'Profile'});
this.props.navigation.navigate('CommonScreen2', { initial: 'Profile'});

// in CommonScreen2 do the reset to the this.props.navigation.state.params.initial
```

Comment: I see. Is there a way of passing the initial param to all components that are navigated to?

Comment: @JPHorta I think that would be really complicated without redux since there is no out of the box solution for that. One solutions come up to my mind is that you can track screens and somehow reset the navigation stack with the proper parameters.

Comment: Ok I understand. So, the best solution would be using redux?

Comment: @JPHorta redux would be a better solution since you can control everything from a single location but redux has disadvantages too I believe. Its pretty much up to you. I don't really know what you are trying to achieve completely but maybe a rethink of your navigation logic could be an option too.